# c# empty array as response from laravel

Tags: c#, laravel, api, post, response

I have a problem with one service and c#, the service is written in laravel and consume by c#, the problem is the response of laravel is not read by c#.

I try the service with postman, and works correctly.

When try with c#, laravel return as response: a empty array when use json or empty string when use a value string from the same request passed.

c# code:

```
        string token =  GetAuthToken();

        var request = WebRequest.Create("url") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);


        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
           streamWriter.Write(activities);
        }
        try
            {

            var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
              (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(),Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    //return a empty array or empty string
                    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;

        }
```

Laravel code:

```
     public function SetActivities(Request $request)
{
    //return value: HULE
    $re = $request[0]['Name'];
    return $re;

}
```

Postman show the return value as: HULE
but in c# the value es: ""

When change the code in laravel for this:

```
 public function SetActivities(Request $request)
{
    $re = 'a';
    return $re;

}
```

Postman: a

C#: a

Why the second work correctly?

Comment: If the return of 'a' works then the problem is something in  $re = $request[0]['Name'];

Comment: Hi Patrick, that sentence works correctly when use postman check, that's weird.

Comment: Found the problem was the request access:  $act = $request->json()->all(); also this: $request->getContent();

Answer (score 0):

Found

correct code:

```
 $request->getContent();
 //also this one works
 $request->json()->all();
```

instead of $request sentence only.